# Calculate the Riemann integral and determinate if is Lebesgue integrability

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

My function is
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\chi_{[n,n+1)}(x)g(x-n),$$ where $$g(x)=\frac{1}{2}-x^2.$$
According to my accounts the Riemann integral gives me $1/3$ and is Lebesgue integrable. Am I right?

Comment: The integral should be calculated over which interval? Also you should add your attempt.

Comment: Integral over what bounds? I assume the real number line?

Comment: sorry, yes in the real line